# xsodata: converter[index] is not a function

Tags: odata, hana, cds, hana-xs, xsodata

I have two entitys in hdbcds:

```
context PyramidDB {
    entity PipelineType {
        key TypeName    : String(200) not null;
            Displayname : String(200) not null;
            Description : String(300);
    };

    entity PyramidType {
        key TypeName    : String(200) not null;
            Displayname : String(200) not null;
            Description : String(500);
            Channel     : Boolean     not null default false;
    };
}
```

From both i will have a OData Service.
xsodata:

```
service namespace "PyramidDBService.services" {
    "PyramidDBService.db::PyramidsDB.PipelineType" as "PipelineType";
    "PyramidDBService.db::PyramidsDB.PyramidType" as "PyramidType";
}
```

With PipelineType is no problem, but at PyramidType i get a error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "converter[index] is not a function"
    }
  }
}
```

can some one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAP support document [SAP Note "2130460 - Functional restrictions of XSOData to OData V2 Specifications for Rev. 90+"](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2130460) lists restrictions of the OData v2 features implemented in XSODATA:

- No support for Function Import
- **No support for Boolean type**
- No supportfor GUID type
- No support for type casts in $filter and $orderby
- No support for $skiptoken
- No support for complex types
- No support for imports of entity types from other services

With HANA 2 and the OData v4 support there, most of these limitations, specifically of the Boolean type support, are removed.